# How to write Ctrl-C handler in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, signals

I tried the following approach:

```
import System.Exit
import System.Posix.Signals
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  installHandler keyboardSignal (Catch (do exitSuccess)) Nothing
  threadDelay (1000000000)
```

But it only outputs:

```
^CTest.hs: ExitSuccess
```

on `Ctrl-C`, instead of exiting. How should I do it properly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the docs of `installHandler`:

> a handler is installed which will invoke action in a new thread when (or shortly after) the signal is received.

and `exitWith:`

> Note: in GHC, exitWith should be called from the main program thread in order to exit the process. When called from another thread, exitWith will throw an ExitException as normal, but the exception will not cause the process itself to exit.

So an `exitSuccess` handler doesn't end the process, and that's expected (although unexpected ;) behaviour.

If you want immediate action,

```
import System.Exit
import System.Posix.Signals
import Control.Concurrent

main :: IO ()
main = do
  tid <- myThreadId
  installHandler keyboardSignal (Catch (killThread tid)) Nothing
  threadDelay (1000000000)
```

kills the thread immediately upon receiving the signal.

Less drastic, if you want a successful exit, would be

```
import System.Exit
import System.Posix.Signals
import Control.Concurrent
import qualified Control.Exception as E

main :: IO ()
main = do
  tid <- myThreadId
  installHandler keyboardSignal (Catch (E.throwTo tid ExitSuccess)) Nothing
  threadDelay (10000000)
```

I think it will also work reliably, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: [`threadDelay`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:threadDelay) "Suspends the current thread for a given number of microseconds", similar to `usleep` in C. Here, we suspend execution for the sole purpose of giving the user enough time to press Ctrl-C.

Comment: Is there a simple way to delay the thread indefinitely instead of a given amount of microseconds?

Comment: @MatthiasBraun Do `threadDelay` in a loop. You could also try to wait on an empty `MVar` that you never fill.