# How to progressively update a GUI in Haskell, with calculations interrupted on user events?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, ghc, cancellation

I'm contemplating writing a program like Qt's [Mandelbrot Sample](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcore-mandelbrot-example.html).  In that sample, GUI/Worker thread separation is established where calculation is performed on a background thread.  As iteratively more detail is provided, image data is sent back to the GUI window for display.  If the mouse pans or zoom while an in-progress calculation is still happening...the old calculation is "canceled" and doesn't run any more.

*(Note: There is no way to safely just kill a running thread in C++.  So the worker has to check a `restart` boolean every now and again during points in the calculation loop...in a cooperative multitasking way.)*

As a new-to-Haskell person, I'm wondering exactly what sort of recourse someone would have for even a very simple version of this.  I've read about [Functional Reactive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming) and it makes (some) sense to me.  But I haven't found anything about asking for a long calculation, getting progressive results from that calculation over time, and then pulling the rug out from under the calculation based on something the user did to start a new one.

This is what I found in searching, and I'm not sure how relevant it is:

[How to write Ctrl-C handler in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441676/how-to-write-ctrl-c-handler-in-haskell)

Does killThread in GHC's concurrency have a safety that other systems don't; making it okay to use for cancellation of this form?  The computations being killed would not be involved in GUI operations--their work would all be where GHC was in control.  But they still would need a way to progressively communicate their progress back to the interface somehow.  So during that signaling it might be using some OS facility and be an "unsafe time".

Comment: You want to run the computation in the background concurrently with the UI thread. If the background computation can return partial results then you can update those as soon as they arise, as well.

Comment: For a problem like this I'd definitely suggest FRP.  You can do this manually with STM channels, locks, mvars, and the like, but your code is going to be very much imperative as you might write it in C++.  FRP will let you worry about the computations and when to send signals where, instead of how to make it concurrent.  That being said, I would say that you should have two event types, one for user input that is received by the computation thread and one for returning partial or finished computations to be handled by the GUI thread.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and no.  `killThread` is GHC is a super-fancy way of setting that `restart` boolean.  Each "capability" in the GHC run-time has a slot for asynchronous exceptions that the run-time checks from time to time and, if it isn't empty will throw the exception in that capability.

Normally, this will kill that thread, although I believe the exception can be caught and recovered from.  Also, while asynchronous exceptions are masked in a thread, this slot is not checked; as soon as the masking ends, the slot is checked and the exception is thrown.  This is true whether it is just a lightweight thread (started via `forkIO`) or a full OS thread (started via `forkOS`).  `forkProcess` is its own beast, though I've heard on IRC that it is safer than the documentation makes it out to be.

In a Haskell-only program, you would communicate back with an IORef, MVar, or TVar (various levels of functionality and safety).  (Most of) The exposed operations on these references mask asynchronous exceptions for small windows so that the references are not left in a "bad" state.  If you need to communicate in some other fashion, you will be responsible for properly masking/unmasking asynchronous exceptions to avoid curruption of your communication channel (and minimizing the "uninterruptable" window).

Comment: Thanks; I'll keep this in mind as I keep reading *(lots of basics to get used to first, but wanted to kind of guide what I look at based on my interest in programs of this pattern)*.  I'd be quite interested to see a "best practices" Haskell version of the Mandelbrot program that had a similar ability to interrupt...be it done with FRP tricks I do not know or killThread...